# Set a powershell Expiry Date

Tags: powershell

I want to make my powershell script expire after a certain date. what code needs to be inserted in the powershell script to do so ? I am lost ! Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for timestamp at the begining of your script and decide to continue if the date difference exceeds a particular number?

```
function HasDatePassed([datetime] $EndDate){
      $StartDate=(GET-DATE)
      $Diff = New-TimeSpan -Start $StartDate -End $EndDate
      if ($Diff.Days -gt 0) {
        Write-Host "Will expire after $($Diff.Days) days"
      }
      else { 
        Write-Host "Expired $($Diff.Days) days ago"
      }
}

HasDatePassed "01/01/2015"
HasDatePassed "01/01/2014"
```

You can put your logic inside the if..else construct

Comment: if i make a powershell exe of the script, any way to show message "script expired " on clicking of the powershell exe ?

Comment: Save it as a script say 'Scriptname' and run the common from Command Prompt powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "& ScriptName.ps1"

Comment: Thanx ! Can you tell me Why have u put two hasdatepassed ?

Comment: That's for testing future and past dates. You can put actual date once